# Forming an inverted ascii triangle art using JS looping

Tags: javascript, function, loops, ascii

Without nesting loops, how are you able to form such an ascii art?

```
####
###
##
#
```

This is what I currently have:

```
function invertTriangle (row) {
  var asteric = "*" * row;
  for ( var y=row; y>=row; y--){
      asteric = asteric - "*";
      console.log(asteric);
  }
};

invertTriangle(10);
```

I will appreciate your help and explanation!

Thank you!

Comment: By using recursion. In just the same way that you can create a recursive function to calculate `n!` (factorial), you can make one to solve this problem.

Comment: I think the OP meant how to do it in one loop. Recursion can still be nested.

Comment: @AaditMShah - yes indeed recursion can be nested - and in fact, without nesting it wouldn't be recursion, would it? :confused: But the question asks for a solution which doesn't involve nested _loops_. Recursion meets the stated requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
var string = "";

for (var i = 0, j = 4, k = 4; i < 10; i++) {
    string += "*";
    if (--j === 0) {
        j = --k;
        string += "\n";
    }
}

alert(string);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you kindly explain to me why you used j and k variables? I'm very unfamiliar with the logic of JS operators, and how JS functions work. Only started learning a few days ago!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing it with recursion.

Basically, you call the function with the number of chars you'd like printed on the first line. It then constructs a string with this many characters in it. It then decrements the number of chars wanted and, if this number is greater than 0, calls itself again and adds the new result to the current result. This continues until we get to a line that requires zero characters. At this point, the function no longer calls itself and the fully constructed string is returned to the original caller.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    byId('triTgt').innerText = makeTriString(40);
}

function makeTriString(nStars)
{
    var str = '';
    for (var i=0; i<nStars; i++)
        str += "*";
    str += "\n";
    nStars--;
    if (nStars > 0)
        str += makeTriString(nStars);
    return str;
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='triTgt'></div>
</body>
</html>
```